# MInecraft 1.13 Redstone display issue in Resource Pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

So far i have got all of the right pieces of redstone displaying, except for when the redstone goes in more than one directions. I've uploaded a picture showing the problem. [image: image of problem]The redstone_dust_dot.png is showing on the lines that intersect, but as you can see, the lines show up through of the dot.  This does not happen with the default textures. How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Chippies how can I fix this

Comment: Ask Mumbo. He had this problem before and fixed it. The problem is that you have multiple overlapping middle pieces. You have to somehow edit the block model to have a separate middle piece and only add the outer pieces by themselves. But I can't tell you how, I'm not an expert with block models. Maybe ask some more accesible people than Mumbo who have made resource packs containing redstone dust block models, for example LapisDemon. And if you get an answer that helps you, you can post it here to help other people (and get some points).

Comment: You should raise the dot texture up by a small amount.

Answer (score 1):

In `redstone_dust_dot.json` change to match:

```
{
    "ambientocclusion": false,
    "textures": {
        "particle": "block/redstone_dust_dot",
        "line": "block/redstone_dust_dot",
        "overlay": "block/redstone_dust_overlay"
    },
    "elements": [
        {   "from": [ 0, 0.26, 0 ],
            "to": [ 16, 0.26, 16 ],
            "shade": false,
            "faces": {
                "up": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16], "texture": "#line", "tintindex": 0 }
            }
        },
        {   "from": [ 0, 0.25, 0 ],
            "to": [ 16, 0.25, 16 ],
            "shade": true,
            "faces": {
                "up": { "uv": [ 0, 0, 16, 16 ], "texture": "#overlay" }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

If on a different version just change the

```
"from": [ 0, 0.25, 0 ],
"to": [ 16, 0.25, 16 ],
```

to

```
"from": [ 0, 0.26, 0 ],
"to": [ 16, 0.26, 16 ],
```

Hope this helps!!

Felix